# Slow response from google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts to create a simple line chart with 1440 points.  The chart is taking around 1.5 seconds to load and draw.  I have read that charts is quick and draws in milliseconds.  Am I doing something wrong with my chart drawing function which slows things down?  My code is:

```
function drawChart() {
  // Set Data
  timestamp = new Date
  console.log("starting chart drawing timestamp: " + timestamp.toISOString())
  var graphData = [["Date/Time", "Height"]]
  for (var i = 0; i < tideHeightTable.length; i++) {
    var dateStr = tideHeightTable[i].DateTime.substring(0,16)
    dateStr = dateStr.replace("T", " ")
    var tideHeight = parseFloat(tideHeightTable[i].Height.toFixed(2))
    graphData.push([dateStr, tideHeight])
  }
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(graphData);
  
  // Set Options
  var options = {
    title: 'Tide Heights for Selected Date Range',
    hAxis: {title: 'Date/Time'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Tide Height'},
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    // animation: {
    //   duration: 1000,
    //   startup: false,
    //   easing: 'inAndOut'
    // }
    titleTextStyle: {bold: true}
  };
  // Draw
  
  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('myChart'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', googleChartsReadyHandler);
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}

function googleChartsReadyHandler(){
  //chart is now rendered
  setBusyState("free")
  timestamp = new Date
  console.log("ending chart drawing timestamp: " + timestamp.toISOString())
}
```

The console.log shows:

> starting chart drawing timestamp: 2021-12-28T22:54:13.893Z ending
> chart drawing timestamp: 2021-12-28T22:54:15.481Z

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say offhand, but FYI `console.time/timeEnd` is better for timing.  Try replacing your current time logging with `console.time("overall")` and `console.timeEnd("overall")`.  Then time a few other sections of the code to see what part is slow.

Comment: how is the data loaded on the page? I've found loading the data table using the constructor in the json format found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) is the fastest...

Comment: Thanks, very useful using console.time.  I have narrowed it down to 1500ms taken up between chart.draw(....) and googleChartsReadyHandler() i.e. all the time is taken in the chart drawing process.  Any further thoughts?

Comment: I was using the new format Line package from google, when I regressed to the Corechart version, speed to draw went from 1500ms to 65ms!  Must be something to do with the Line package then.

Comment: Clarifying!  I am using Material charts, when I switch to Corecharts the time to draw drops from 1500ms to 65ms.  I much prefer the material charts so would be good to understand if i can make them draw faster.

Comment: I'm only guessing, but I wouldn't be surprised if the slow one is doing some expensive operation by default (eg. antialiasing).  Maybe it's possible to disable slow options, so if it has such options you could try that.  Beyond that, you might be looking at workarounds like rendering with 1/10 the number of points to get something on screen quickly, then rendering with all the points immediately after.

Comment: Thanks.  I have dropped points but moved to the older Corecharts, which, with alot of paramaterisation I can get to look better than Material Charts (I have found that most of the options are ignored in Material Charts).